# Change database data through onclick button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I am unsure of how to change/update the data in my database through react.

**My database:**

```
const Package = new mongoose.Schema({
  packageID =  {type: String},
  packageStatus = {type: String, enum: [packed, delivered, received], default: 'packed' },
})
```

1. how do I refer to packageStatus and their enum values in react/class component? How should I call them?
2. The default value is 'packed', I want to change it to 'delivered' when a button is clicked (no text fields involved).

```
class PackageStatus extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            packageStatus: 'packed'
        }
        this.updateStatus = this.updateStatus.bind(this);
    }

    updateStatus(){
        this.setState =({
            packageStatus: 'delivered'
        }
        )
    
    render(){

        return (
            <div?
                <button onClick={()=> packageStatus(this)}>Update Status</button>       
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default PackageStatus
```

The code above changes the text displayed but not the status in the database, so how do I change the data in the database?

Next, I would want to display text depending on what the status in the database is. I'm not sure how to link **isDelivered** to the condition of the database.

**For example**

```
class Status extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDelivered: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    let { isDelivered } = this.state;
    let status;

    if (isDelivered) {
      status = <h1>Delivered<h1>
    } else {
      status = <h1>Packing in progress<h1>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {status}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Status;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you using node to communicate with the database? Because in order to communicate with the database, you need to have a backend server.

Answer (score 1):

Well interfacing, a frontend framework like **REACT** with a database, an easier approach would be create **apiEndpoints** of which you would use make **fetch or axios**  to make **httpRequests** which communicates to these endpoints, in turn communicate with the **database** to give you your desired response. A solution approach to your problem is as follows:

1. Create the schema using mongoose in node

   ```
      const mongoose = require('mongoose')
      const { Schema } = mongoose
      const PackageSchema = new Schema({
          packageID: {
             type: String,
          },
          packageStatus: {
             type: String,
             enum: ["packed", "delivered", "received"],
             default: 'packed'
          }
      })

       module.exports = mongoose.model('package',PackageSchema)
   ```
2. Create the apiEndpoints or routes to interface this schema with FrontEnd(React) and Backend(eg; mongodb)

   ```
      const express = require('express');
      const router = express.Router();
      require('dotenv').config()
      const package = require('../model/packageModel');

          router.get('/allpackages', async(req, res) => {
             try{
                   const getAllPackages = await package.find();
                   res.json(getAllPackages);
              }catch(err){
                    res.json({
                     message: err
               })
            }
          })

         router.post('/addPackage',async(req, res) => {
                 const pack = new package({
                 packageID: req.body.packageID,
                 packageStatus: req.body.packageStatus
                })
              try{
                   const savedPost = await pack.save();
                   res.json(savedPost);
              }catch(err){
              res.json({
                    message: err
              })
             }
          })

       router.patch('/updatePackageStatus', async (req, res) => {
        try {
             const updatePackageStatus = await package.updateOne(
              { _id: req.body.packageID },
              {
                 $set: {
                      packageStatus: req.body.packageStatus
                }
             }
           )
           res.json(updatePackageStatus)
          }catch (err) {
          res.json({
            message: err
         })
       }
     })

    module.exports = router;
   ```
3. Use **POSTMAN or any other of choice** to test endpoints with schema, and database, to see if you get the desired results. After testing out the above, with **POSTMAN**, all desired operations work as expected, and you should have no problem, interfacing it with any **Frontend Framework(Angular, React, Vue)** now.

   ```
       GET  http://localhost:3000/package/allpackages
       POST http://localhost:3000/package/addPackage
       PATCH http://localhost:3000/package/updatePackageStatus
   ```

sample screenshot shown below
[fetch api Endpoints via postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD0cd.png)